# Where can I find documentation for the Mysql::Result class?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Ruby on Rails project, I can get results of a query by running

```
a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from maluuba")
```

In the rails console, I can see that the object type is Mysql::Result. Does anyone know where I can find documentation for this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord will return the objects from whichever MySQL gem you are using. The most popular gem at the moment is the `mysql` gem, which has [documentation online at rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/frames).

If you are using a different gem, you can probably find the documentation for it from the [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/) site.

I don't use the `ri` command, but it may have info as well, without having to go online. (Can anyone else confirm?)

Comment: Thanks. Just for completeness, I checked the Gemfile file in the root of my project and did indeed find an entry for 'mysql' there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of .execute you could use .select_all, this will return an array with the result.

So use: a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select * from maluuba")